# Multiple declaration of function C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have to refactor a project and thought of separating the sources and header files. It worked great for the "Empregado" class, but when I tried to replicate it to the "Engenheiro" class I got the multiple declaration error

A screenshot of the error I'm getting when trying to build the project

[image: Cmake error]

```
CMakeFiles\exercicio_revisao_refatoracao.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `ZNK10Engenheiro7getNomeB5cxx11Ev':
D:/UFMG/UFMG-DCC204/CPP/Modulo3/exercicio-revisao-refatoracao/Engenheiro.cpp:5: multiple definition of `Engenheiro::getNome[abi:cxx11]() const'
CMakeFiles\exercicio_revisao_refatoracao.dir/objects.a(Engenheiro.cpp.obj):D:/UFMG/UFMG-DCC204/CPP/Modulo3/exercicio-revisao-refatoracao/Engenheiro.cpp:5: first defined here
CMakeFiles\exercicio_revisao_refatoracao.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `ZN10Engenheiro7setNomeERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE':
D:/UFMG/UFMG-DCC204/CPP/Modulo3/exercicio-revisao-refatoracao/Engenheiro.cpp:9: multiple definition of `Engenheiro::setNome(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
CMakeFiles\exercicio_revisao_refatoracao.dir/objects.a(Engenheiro.cpp.obj):D:/UFMG/UFMG-DCC204/CPP/Modulo3/exercicio-revisao-refatoracao/Engenheiro.cpp:9: first defined here
CMakeFiles\exercicio_revisao_refatoracao.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `ZNK10Engenheiro11getProjetosEv':
D:/UFMG/UFMG-DCC204/CPP/Modulo3/exercicio-revisao-refatoracao/Engenheiro.cpp:13: multiple definition of `Engenheiro::getProjetos() const'
CMakeFiles\exercicio_revisao_refatoracao.dir/objects.a(Engenheiro.cpp.obj):D:/UFMG/UFMG-DCC204/CPP/Modulo3/exercicio-revisao-refatoracao/Engenheiro.cpp:13: first defined here
CMakeFiles\exercicio_revisao_refatoracao.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `ZN10Engenheiro11setProjetosEi':
D:/UFMG/UFMG-DCC204/CPP/Modulo3/exercicio-revisao-refatoracao/Engenheiro.cpp:17: multiple definition of `Engenheiro::setProjetos(int)'
CMakeFiles\exercicio_revisao_refatoracao.dir/objects.a(Engenheiro.cpp.obj):D:/UFMG/UFMG-DCC204/CPP/Modulo3/exercicio-revisao-refatoracao/Engenheiro.cpp:17: first defined here
CMakeFiles\exercicio_revisao_refatoracao.dir/objects.a(Vendedor.cpp.obj): In function `ZN8Vendedor7setNomeERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE':
D:/UFMG/UFMG-DCC204/CPP/Modulo3/exercicio-revisao-refatoracao/Vendedor.cpp:5: multiple definition of `Vendedor::setNome(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
CMakeFiles\exercicio_revisao_refatoracao.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):D:/UFMG/UFMG-DCC204/CPP/Modulo3/exercicio-revisao-refatoracao/Vendedor.cpp:5: first defined here
CMakeFiles\exercicio_revisao_refatoracao.dir/objects.a(Vendedor.cpp.obj): In function `ZNK8Vendedor7getNomeB5cxx11Ev':
D:/UFMG/UFMG-DCC204/CPP/Modulo3/exercicio-revisao-refatoracao/Vendedor.cpp:9: multiple definition of `Vendedor::getNome[abi:cxx11]() const'
CMakeFiles\exercicio_revisao_refatoracao.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):D:/UFMG/UFMG-DCC204/CPP/Modulo3/exercicio-revisao-refatoracao/Vendedor.cpp:9: first defined here
CMakeFiles\exercicio_revisao_refatoracao.dir/objects.a(Vendedor.cpp.obj): In function `ZN8Vendedor15quotaTotalAnualEv':
D:/UFMG/UFMG-DCC204/CPP/Modulo3/exercicio-revisao-refatoracao/Vendedor.cpp:13: multiple definition of `Vendedor::quotaTotalAnual()'
CMakeFiles\exercicio_revisao_refatoracao.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):D:/UFMG/UFMG-DCC204/CPP/Modulo3/exercicio-revisao-refatoracao/Vendedor.cpp:13: first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have uploaded all the files to GitHub https://github.com/jvbraganca/exercicio-revisao-refatoracao/tree/multiple-declaration-error

The header and source file for Engenheiro are here:

Engenheiro.h

```cpp
#ifndef ENGENHEIRO_H
#define ENGENHEIRO_H

#include <string>
#include "Empregado.h"

class Engenheiro : public Empregado {

public:
    const std::string &getNome() const;

    void setNome(const std::string &nome);

    int getProjetos() const;

    void setProjetos(int projetos);

private:
    std::string nome;
    int projetos;

};

#endif //ENGENHEIRO_H
```

Engenheiro.cpp

```cpp
#include "Empregado.h"


void Empregado::setHorasTrabalhadas(double horasTrabalhadas) {
    Empregado::horasTrabalhadas = horasTrabalhadas;
}

void Empregado::setSalarioHora(double salarioHora) {
    Empregado::salarioHora = salarioHora;
}

void Empregado::setQuotaMensalVendas(double quotaMensalVendas) {
    Empregado::quotaMensalVendas = quotaMensalVendas;
}

double Empregado::getHorasTrabalhadas() const {
    return horasTrabalhadas;
}

double Empregado::getSalarioHora() const {
    return salarioHora;
}

double Empregado::getQuotaMensalVendas() const {
    return quotaMensalVendas;
}

double Empregado::getPagamentoMes() const {

    double horasTrabalhadas = getHorasTrabalhadas();

    /**
     * Calcula as horas extras trabalhadas, bônus de 50% se
     * tiver mais que 8 horas extras trabalhadas.
     */
    if (horasTrabalhadas > MAX_HORAS_TRABALHADAS) {
        double x = horasTrabalhadas - MAX_HORAS_TRABALHADAS;
        horasTrabalhadas += x / 2;
    }
    return horasTrabalhadas * salarioHora;
}

void Empregado::printInfo(const std::string &nome, double salario, int projetosOuQuota, int tipoFuncionario) {
    if (tipoFuncionario == 1) {
        std::cout << "Nome: " << nome << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Salario Mes: " << salario << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Projetos: " << projetosOuQuota << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    } else if (tipoFuncionario == 2) {
        std::cout << "Nome: " << nome << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Salario Mes: " << salario << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Quota vendas: " << projetosOuQuota << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    } else {
        throw "Tipo de funcionário não reconhecido!";
    }
}
Empregado::~Empregado() = default;
```

I can't see where I am declaring it multiple times. Maybe it is a dummy question

Any help is welcome, thanks!

**Solved: I was importing the source file instead of the header file on main.cpp**

Comment: please post a [mcve]. If you cannot reduce the amount of code needed to a small example then that is the problem that you should adress first

Comment: You have `#include "Engenheiro.cpp"` in `main.cpp`. Include headers, not source files.

Comment: There are two things you need to learn to understand this problem: The first is the difference between a *declaration* and a *definition*. The declaration is simply telling the compiler that a symbol exists somewhere. The definition is the implementation of the symbol (like the function implementation).

Comment: The second thing you need to learn is about [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). In short a translation unit is a single source file with all its included header files (or, as in your case, included source files). The C++ compiler only deals with single translation units, it doesn't know anything about other translation units or source files.

Comment: Thanks for the help Nathan and Some programmer dude. Changing the import from .cpp to .h solved it. idclev I edited the text so it's more readable!

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in main.cpp you are including source files.

```
#include "Engenheiro.cpp"
#include "Vendedor.cpp"
```

You should include the corresponding header files instead.

```
#include "Engenheiro.h"
#include "Vendedor.h
```

This fixes the problem:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Checking Build System
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: exercicio_revisao_refatoracao, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>Building Custom Rule C:/Users/juanr/Downloads/exercicio-revisao-refatoracao/CMakeLists.txt
2>Empregado.cpp
2>Engenheiro.cpp
2>main.cpp
2>Vendedor.cpp
2>Generating Code...
2>exercicio_revisao_refatoracao.vcxproj -> C:\Users\juanr\Downloads\exercicio-revisao-refatoracao\build\Debug\exercicio_revisao_refatoracao.exe
========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```